# How to make pedestrians appear at AreaNode with attractors from a pedSource

Tags: anylogic

I am working on an evacuation project for a floor and would like to create a distribution of pedestrians from the pedSource block. These pedestrians will already appear in an area when I run the simulation. I want to obtain a fixed number of pedestrians in one area while the rest is distributed to other areas.

I have made a collection of areas that pedestrians will appear using allLocations (area, area1, area2 and OfficeArea). The event is triggered by an event and using a delay block. The max amount of pedestrians at the given floor is 100

[Image of block flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0TOu.png)

[Image of floor layout plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxSc3.png)

This is the code I tried where pedestrians would appear in the areas:

```
    allLocations.get(uniform_discr(0, allLocations.size()-1))
```

I expect a fixed 10 number of pedestrians in the office area and positioned where I set the attractors, but the actual result shows more than 10 number of pedestrians and do not appear at the set attractor.

[Image of actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Efg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting an attractor as a target for pedestrians is according to the [documentation](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/markup/PedAttractor.html?resultof=%22%61%74%74%72%61%63%74%6f%72%73%22%20%22%61%74%74%72%61%63%74%6f%72%22%20) only working for the blocks *pedWait* and *pedGoTo* (I could actually only get it to work with *pedWait*, not with *pedGoTo*). Therefore you cannot initialize agents directly onto attractors using the initial location or the jumpTo() function.

You have several options as a workaround:

1. Extract the x,y coordinates of the attractor, and use the type *point(x,y)* to define the initial location or the location for the jumpTo()
2. Instead of using (graphical) attractors consider just defining points by code directly
3. Use very small individual areas instead of one large area with attractors
4. Use a pedWait block in your process flow and let your pedestrians 'walk' to their initial positions. Give the model a short time until everybody is on the desired location before starting your evacuation. You can also run the model in super fast mode during this initial phase, so that it will barely be visible.